# Home page (index.php) of a website for finding products

Tags: php, html, typescript

My code is basically the home page (index.php) of a website for finding products. It accesses a database table to get a list of all countries and then populates a `<select>` so the user can add a country to their search filter while finding products.

1. Are there any website "code smells" in this code?
2. Is it considered clean to have a big PHP block to access the database inside the HTML? It seems kind of like I am mixing logic with presentation.
3. Can my PHP database query be shifted into a separate file somehow?
4. Can the tiny `<script type="text/javasript">` tag somehow be put into a separate file?
5. Is it bad practice to have a global JavaScript variable called `allCountries` inside index.php so that I can access it in country.ts?

**index.php:**

```
<!-- This is the home page -->
<html>
    <head>
        <title>The Vegan Repository</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <!-- Load libraries -->
        <!-- System.js -->
        <script 
            src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/systemjs/0.18.4/system-csp-production.js"></script>
        <!-- JQuery -->
        <script 
            src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
        <link 
            rel="stylesheet" 
            href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
            integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7"
            crossorigin="anonymous">
        <!-- Bootstrap JS -->
        <script 
            src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" 
            integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <!-- Knockout JS -->
        <script 
            src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
        <!-- Styles -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/image.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/text.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/header.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/form.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/select.css">
        <?php
            $host = 'localhost';
            $port = 8889;
            $servername = "$host:$port";
            $username = "root";
            $password = "root";
            $db = "myDB";

            // Create connection
            $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $db);
            // Check connection
            if ($conn->connect_error) {
                die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
            } 

            $sql = "SELECT name, geonameId FROM countryinfo";
            $result = $conn->query($sql);
            $allCountries = [];
            if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                $rows = array ();
                while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                    $country = array(
                        "name" => $row['name'],
                        "geonameId" => $row['geonameId']
                    );
                    $allCountries[] = $country;
                }
            }
            $conn->close();
            ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var allCountries = <?php echo json_encode($allCountries, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT) ?>;
        </script>
    </head>
    <body >
        <div style="margin-bottom: 100px;" class="full_size dimmed">
            <div style="position:fixed; z-index: -1;">
                <video 
                    style="position:fixed;" 
                    autoplay loop muted
                    poster="assets/images/home_page/polina.jpg" 
                    id="bgvid">
                    <!--<source src="polina.webm" type="video/webm">-->
                    <source src="assets/videos/polina.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                </video>
            </div>
            <div class="header dim">
                <a href="http://www.w3schools.com" >
                    <h5 id="app-name" class="nav-item clickable white-text medium-text left-text">THE VEGAN REPOSITORY</h5>
                </a>
                <a href="http://www.w3schools.com" >
                    <h5 (click)="clicked()" id="sign-in-button" class="nav-item clickable brand-colour-text medium-text right-text with-border">SIGN UP FREE</h5>
                </a>
                <a href="http://www.w3schools.com" >
                    <h5 class="nav-item clickable white-text medium-text right-text">LOGIN</h5>
                </a>
                <a href="#home_page_footer" >
                    <h5 class="nav-item clickable white-text medium-text right-text" >BLOG</h5>
                </a>
                <a href="#home_page_footer" >
                    <h5 class="nav-item clickable white-text medium-text right-text" >ABOUT</h5>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div id="motto-text" class="vertical-center">
                <h5 class="white-text medium-text">THE VEGAN REPOSITORY</h5>
                <h1 id="main-text" class=" text-center white-text light-text extra-large-text">FIND VEGAN PRODUCTS NEAR YOU</h1>
                <a id="try-now-button" class="with-border clickable" href="#find-vegan-products-page" >
                    <h5  class=" text-center medium-text">TRY NOW</h5>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script>
            document.createElement('video');
        </script>
        <![endif]-->
        <div id="find-vegan-products-page" style="height:900px;">
            <div class="form-background">
                <div class="container-fluid" style="padding: 40px;">
                    <h1>Filter Your Search!</h1>
                    <form role="form">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
                                <div class="select">
                                    <span class="arr"></span>
                                    <select data-bind="options: _countries,
                                        optionsText: 'name',
                                        optionsValue: 'geonameId',
                                        value: selectedCountry,
                                        optionsCaption: 'Country'">
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
                                <div class="select">
                                    <span class="arr"></span>
                                    <select data-bind="options: _regions,
                                        optionsText: 'name',
                                        optionsValue: 'name',
                                        value: selectedCity,
                                        optionsCaption: 'Region'">
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div id='container'>
            <div>always showing</div>
            <div id='loading' data-bind="visible: isLoading">Loading...</div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <button data-bind="click: loadData">Simulate Load
        </div>
        </div>
        <script src="scripts/scroll_to_anchor.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/xml2json.min.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/country.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**country.ts (TypeScript):**

```
class HomeViewModel {
    _countriesList = [];
    _regionsList = [];
    _countries = ko.observableArray();
    _regions = ko.observableArray();
    selectedCountry = ko.observable();

    constructor(allCountries) {
        for (var index = 0; index < allCountries.length; index++) {
            this._countriesList.push(allCountries[index]);
        }
        this._countries(this._countriesList);
        this.selectedCountry.subscribe(this.updateCities.bind(this))
    }

    updateCities(geonameId) {
        var self = this;
        self._regionsList = [];
        $.ajax({
            url: `http://api.geonames.org/children?geonameId=${geonameId}&username=elion`
        }).then(function(allCitiesXML) {
            var allCitiesJSON = xml2json(allCitiesXML);
            var allCities = JSON.parse(allCitiesJSON);
            for (var index = 1; index < allCities.geonames.length - 1; index++) {
                self._regionsList.push(allCities.geonames[index].geoname);
            }
            self._regions(self._regionsList);
        });
    }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    var _homeViewModel: HomeViewModel = new HomeViewModel(allCountries);
    ko.applyBindings(_homeViewModel);
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can separate your db connection in some db.php file and include it on this

```
page "include('db.php')"
$host = 'localhost';
$port = 8889;
$servername = "$host:$port";
$username = "root";
$password = "root";
$db = "myDB";
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $db);
// Check connection
if ($conn - > connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: ".$conn - > connect_error);
}
```